# Sqlite self join using alias

Tags: sql, sqlite, self-join

I have such sql query:

```
SELECT LeftCurrency.LeftCurrency, RightCurrency.RightCurrency FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT [SecurityData].[Value] AS 'LeftCurrency'
  FROM [SecurityData]
  JOIN [Fields] ON [Fields].[Id] = [SecurityData].[FieldId]
  WHERE [Fields].[Mnemonic] = 'CRNCY'
) AS LeftCurrency
JOIN 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT [SecurityData].[Value] AS 'RightCurrency'
  FROM [SecurityData]
  JOIN [Fields] ON [Fields].[Id] = [SecurityData].[FieldId]
  WHERE [Fields].[Mnemonic] = 'CRNCY'
) AS RightCurrency
ON LeftCurrency.LeftCurrency != RightCurrency.RightCurrency
```

it works ok, but I have two similar sub-queries.

Also I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT [SecurityData].[Value] AS 'Currency'
  FROM [SecurityData]
  JOIN [Fields] ON [Fields].[Id] = [SecurityData].[FieldId]
  WHERE [Fields].[Mnemonic] = 'CRNCY'
) AS leftCurrency, leftCurrency AS rightCurrency
WHERE leftCurrency.Currency != rightCurrency.Currency
```

But it doesn't work. 
So is it possible to get rid of sub-query duplication?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Unless I'm glazing over something aren't those two inline views exactly the same? If so why would you expect that they ever contain different values?

Comment: They are exactly the same. This query will return all pairs of subqueries result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite 3.8.3 or later, you could use a common table expression:

```
WITH Currency(Currency) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT [SecurityData].[Value]
    FROM [SecurityData]
    JOIN [Fields] ON [Fields].[Id] = [SecurityData].[FieldId]
    WHERE [Fields].[Mnemonic] = 'CRNCY'
)
SELECT LeftCurrency.Currency AS LeftCurrency,
       RightCurrency.Currency AS RightCurrency
FROM Currency AS LeftCurrency
JOIN Currency AS RightCurrency ON LeftCurrency.Currency != RightCurrency.Currency
```

Alternatively, use a temporary view.